# Python: How to change all instances of "timestamp" in .JSON file to a date-time object

Tags: json, python-2.7, datetime, timestamp

I have a LocationHistory.json file that has location data stored. The data looks like this:

```
{
 "data" : {
   "items" : [ {
     "kind" : "latitude#location",
     "timestampMs" : "1374870896803",
     "latitude" : 34.9482949,
     "longitude" : -85.3245474,
     "accuracy" : 2149
   }, {
     "kind" : "latitude#location",
     "timestampMs" : "1374870711762",
     "latitude" : 34.9857898,
     "longitude" : -85.3526902,
     "accuracy" : 2016"
   }]
  }
}
```

There are almost a thousand instances like these in the file, I'm trying to simplify the idea.
I then read the data in through the following code:

```
json_file = open('LocationHistory.json')
json_string = json_file.read()
json_data = json.loads(json_string)

locations = json_data["data"]["items"]
```

Now I want to change all the occurrences of "timestampMs" to a date-time object. I found through answered problems on stackoverflow that the following code can help me do this:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
    int("timestampMs")
).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Also this way:

```
dateObject = datetime.fromtimestap(timestampMs / 1000)
otherFormat = dateObject.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

My problem is that I'm not familiar with JSON and I do not know how to loop or iterate over all the occurrences of "timestampMs" in the LocationHistory.json file and change all the "timestampsMs" from i.e 1374870896803 to i.e 2014-09-03.....

I tried:

```
for location in locations:
   print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
    int("timestampMs")
   ).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
   )
```

(This gives a Invalid Syntax error when I try to run it)

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the data from the location dictionary you can use the get method and then divide the integer  by 1000 to get the timestamp without milliseconds:

```
for location in locations:
    print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int(location.get("timestampMs"))/1000
    ).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much David, that solved the problem! I appreciate your time :) If this is not a problem, this only prints out the right datetime, how do I change all the timestampsMs permanently? Do I say: for location in locations:   locations = datetime....ect (instead of print)

Comment: or do I say:   for location in locations:             location.get("timestampMs") = datetime.datetime.fromtime.....      The reason I'm asking is, I then write this data to an output file, but the output still says the timestamp value i.e 1374870896803 not the datetime. Thanks

Comment: it is incorrect unless the local timezone is utc and you don't want to preserve milliseconds. btw, It is pointless to use `d.get(key)` here (`d[key]` works as well)

Answer (score 2):

To get POSIX timestamps from a json file and convert them into naive datetime objects that represent UTC time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import io
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

with io.open('LocationHistory.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
for item in data['data']['items']:
    timestamp_millis = int(item['timestampMs'])
    utc_time = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(milliseconds=timestamp_millis)
    print(utc_time.isoformat() + 'Z')
```

#### Output

```
2013-07-26T20:34:56.803000Z
2013-07-26T20:31:51.762000Z
```

Notice: milliseconds are preserved.

Comment: Thank you J.F Sebastian. I'll have to post another question it seems to answer my next problem. I don't really want to print out the data, but rather write all the json data to a .kml file (including the changed datetime data). What do you suggest? Post a new question?

Comment: what I am aiming for is something like: for location in locations: kml_file.write(locations)  to put it simply...

Comment: specify what is the specific issue, [create a minimal code example that demonstrates it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mvce), include the example input, *the desired output*, and what you've got instead. Don't paraphrase the error: include the full traceback verbatim as is. [Post all this info as a new question or update your current question if it is the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Please excuse. When I started out on stack, I posted questions with various problems, and always got "down" marked. So I try to make my questions simpler to understand. I'll keep what you said in mind from now on

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look :)

Comment: J.F Sebastian, if you could spare a moment, could you look at my problem in this thread. I'm sure it will be very simple for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870295/python-change-certain-json-data-and-write-to-output-file