# Python: Change certain JSON data and write to output file

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am trying to parse a .json file into a .kml file to be used by a plotting program. I am going to give a set a data samples to simplify the issue:

I have a LocationHistory.json file that has the following structure:

```
{
 "data" : {
   "items" : [ {
     "kind" : "latitude#location",
     "timestampMs" : "1374870896803",
     "latitude" : 34.9482949,
     "longitude" : -85.3245474,
     "accuracy" : 2149
   }, {
     "kind" : "latitude#location",
     "timestampMs" : "1374870711762",
     "latitude" : 34.9857898,
     "longitude" : -85.3526902,
     "accuracy" : 2016"
   }]
  }
}
```

I define a function that parses the json data and then I want to feed it into a "placemark" string to write (output) into a "location.kml" file:

```
import json
import datetime

def parse_jason_data_to_kml_file():
   kml_file = open('location.kml', "r+")

   #Here I parse the info inside the LocationHistory.json file
   json_file = open('LocationHistory.json')
   json_string = json_file.read()
   json_data = json.loads(json_string)

   locations = json_data["data"]["items"]

   # Next, I create a placemark string template:
   placemark = ["<Placemark>",
                "<TimeStamp><when>%(timestampMs)r</when></TimeStamp>",
                "<ExtendedData>",
                "<Data name=\"accuracy\">",
                "<value>%(accuracy)r</value>]",
                "</Data>",
                "</ExtendedData><Point><coordinates>%(longitude)r, %(latitude)r</coordinates></Point>",
                "</Placemark>"]
   placemark = "\n".join(placemark)

   # Now I loop through the json data and write the json data into the
   # placemark templete and write each placemark to a KML file.
   for location in locations:
       temp = placemark % location
       kml_file.write("\n" + temp + "\n")

   kml_file.close()
   json_file.close()

   parse_jason_data_to_kml_file()
```

The aim of this code is to write the placemark string that contains the .json data, into the location.ml file, from the placemark string that looks like this:

```
<Placemark>
<TimeStamp><when>the “timestampMS” value from the JSON data item</when></TimeStamp>
<ExtendedData>
<Data name=”accuracy”>
<value> the “accuracy” value from the JSON data item </value>
</Data>
</ExtendedData><Point><coordinates>”longitude,latitude”</coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>
```

To an output, which should look like this:

```
<Placemark>
<TimeStamp><when>u'1374870896803'</when></TimeStamp>
<ExtendedData>
<Data name=”accuracy”>
<value>2149</value>
</Data>
</ExtendedData><Point><coordinates>-85.3245474,34.9482949</coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>

<Placemark>
<TimeStamp><when>u'1374870711762'</when></TimeStamp>
<ExtendedData>
<Data name=”accuracy”>
<value>2016</value>
</Data>
</ExtendedData><Point><coordinates>-85.3526902,34.9857898</coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>
```

All is working well as it should but my problem comes in where I need to change all the "timestampMs" info (as seen in LocationHistory.json file) from eg. 1374870896803 to eg. 2013-07-26T10:24:24Z. 
With this code I can print out the timestampMs as datetime objects:

```
for location in locations:
   print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(location.get("timestampMs"))/1000).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

So in other words: I want to change each timestamp to look like this: (Notice the datetime on the top as the timestamp)

```
<Placemark>
<TimeStamp><when>2013-07-26T22:34:56Z</when></TimeStamp>
<ExtendedData>
<Data name=”accuracy”>
<value>2149</value>
</Data>
</ExtendedData><Point><coordinates>-85.3245474,34.9482949</coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>
```

Thank You

Comment: If you ever switch to Pyrhon 3 then `open('...json')` may fail with non-UTF8 locale. That is why I've used `io.open(..,encoding='utf-8')`, to make the code work on both Python 2 and 3. Use `cgi.escape()`,  to escape `<>&` (and quotes inside attributes) characters for xml (to defend from malicious/buggy input).

Comment: I was wondering why you included the extra "import io" and [with io.open('LocationHistory.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:] Now it makes sense! I'll start to do that then with all future json files.  Where would you use the: cgi.escape() command?

Comment: `<>&` chars are special inside xml. Compare `"<code>{expr}</code>".format(expr='>(2 & 1) < 2')` against `"<code>{expr}</code>".format(expr=cgi.escape('>(2 & 1) < 2'))`

Comment: I hope this isn't a dumb question: but how do I compare the two? Should I implement them in my code?

Comment: copy-paste the code into Python Interactive console (REPL) and compare the results. You can check it online if you don't want to run python on your device http://repl.it

Comment: Why when I paste the second code inside the shell, and run it, it gives an error: name 'cgi' is not defined? the first output looks like this:   '<code>>(2 & 1) < 2</code>'

Comment: put `import cgi` at the top.

Comment: Ah, so the result changes to this: '<code>&gt;(2 &amp; 1) &lt; 2</code>'. Interesting! I'll see what I can do with this as I progress. Thanks!

Comment: if you want to produce well formed xml then you should escape the special characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a step to the beginning of the for loop:

```
location['timestampMs'] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(location.get("timestampMs"))/1000).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

Comment: hahaha Ag man.. I swear I tried it but now it works thanks to you. I appreciate your time and help @mr nick, I thank you! :)

Comment: mr nick, why when I do this does it display: '2013-07-26T22:34:56Z' instead of 2013-07-26T22:34:56Z (without quote marks). And how can I remove it? I tried location['timestamp'].split("'")

Comment: @LeeVenter In the string template, change the `%(timestampMs)r` to `%(timestampMs)s`.

Comment: @LeeVenter: [`fromtimestamp()` is incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865634/python-how-to-change-all-instances-of-timestamp-in-json-file-to-a-date-time/32865961#comment53566362_32865961). At the very least  use `utcfromtimestamp()` here. To preserve milliseconds, use `*1e-3` instead of `/1000` (Python 2) or the explicit formula from my answer (exact answer, no precision loss with floats or platform limits on  the range) and append `.%f` to the time format string. If you don't want to preserve milliseconds then use `//1000`, to make it explicit that you want to truncate the input.

Comment: Thank you @mr nick, that indeed solved the problem (to remove the ' ' around the timestamp) :)

Comment: Yet again @J.F. Sebastian, thank you for your input. Your answer to my other question to get the timedate and preserve milliseconds also works. I will most definitely give your input a further try, as its more technical than I am use to, but definitely something important. When I implemented the extra things the output looked perfect! Thanks for also taking the time to help me with another question. Have a great evening!

Comment: @LeeVenter: do you understand that the local timezone may have non-zero UTC offset? fromtimestamp() here leads to the result that may be *wrong* by several *hours*! You may not understand it but the person who answer the question should.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, no I didn't know. I did indeed see a change in the timedate output in the location.kml file. I added the //1000 (double dash) and I also added the "utc"fromtimestamp(). The output looks perfect now. I don't mind to preserve milliseconds atm, but I'm going to play around more with this, and I'll use all the ideas you provided me with in the next practice. I really learn a lot from you, and I do appreciate your time :)